# Mysql select double constant

Tags: mysql, select, double, constants

This is not allowed in Mysql:

```
SELECT CAST(0 as DOUBLE) as ZERO
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague found the answer:

```
SELECT 0.0 + '0' as ZERO
```

Does the trick.

Comment: It returns decimal NOT double.

Comment: @NadeemJamali: just tried it again and it does return a double. Maybe that's my version of mysql v5.1.45 with MyISAM

Answer (score 1):

When using `CAST`, the type can be one of the following:

```
BINARY[(N)]
CHAR[(N)]
DATE
DATETIME
DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
SIGNED [INTEGER]
TIME
UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
```

So your example would be:

```
SELECT CAST(0 as DECIMAL) as ZERO
```

You can optionally specify the precision allowed, e.g.:

```
SELECT CAST(0 as DECIMAL(18,8)) as ZERO
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to cast to `DECIMAL`, not `DOUBLE`. Here's the official documentation with a list of types: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Answer (score 0):

I allways used decimal, in the docs: "The maximum range of DECIMAL values is the same as for DOUBLE"

so do a SELECT cast(0 as Decimal) as ZERO;

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do it, the types you can cast to are documented here: [MySQl Docs - Cast Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html)

If you describe more precisely what you want to archive it would be easier for us to answer.